# Variadic template with function, inputs and outputs types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to understand how to create and call variadic templates with function, inpus args and output args types. I wrote this toy example:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename Func, typename... Inputs, typename... Outputs>
std::tuple<double, Outputs...> foo(int init, Func&& func, Inputs&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
};

int main () {
    int init = 6;
    double mult = 2.3;
    std::tuple<double, double> bar = foo(
        init,
        [](int init_, double mult_) { 
            double res = init_ * mult_;
            return std::make_tuple(res, 4.1);
        },
        mult
    );
    int out = std::get<0>(bar);
    return out;
}
```

However, it doesn't compile. How should I modify it to get *13* as result?

I get this error message:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:11:41: error: conversion from 'tuple<double>' to non-scalar type 'tuple<double, double>' requested
   11 |     std::tuple<double, double> bar = foo(
      |                                      ~~~^
   12 |         init,
      |         ~~~~~                            
   13 |         [](int init_, double mult_) {
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    
   14 |             double res = init_ * mult_;
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
   15 |             return std::make_tuple(res, 4.1);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   16 |         },
      |         ~~                               
   17 |         mult
      |         ~~~~                             
   18 |     );
      |     ~                                    
<source>: In instantiation of 'std::tuple<double, Outputs ...> foo(int, Func&&, Inputs&& ...) [with Func = main()::<lambda(int, double)>; Inputs = {double&}; Outputs = {}]':
<source>:18:5:   required from here
<source>:5:72: error: could not convert 'main()::<lambda(int, double)>(init, std::forward<double&>((* & args#0)))' from 'tuple<double, double>' to 'tuple<double>'
    5 |     return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
      |                                                                        ^
      |                                                                        |
      |                                                                        tuple<double, double>
```

Comment: "It dosen't compile" so what do you get as error ?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to deduce `Outputs`? It's only present in the return value.

Comment: Do you really need this Outputs? You can replace return type with auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this template function as:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Inputs>
auto foo(int init, Func&& func, Inputs&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
}
```

The problem with the original version is with `typename... Outputs`, they cannot be deduced. You would need to specify them explicitly - but this is impossible because there are two variadic packs in that template - so it is impossible to say where Inputs... ends and where Outputs starts.

Alternatively - you can just specify one result typename - and specify that type:

```
template<typename Output, typename Func, typename... Inputs>
Output foo(int init, Func&& func, Inputs&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
}
```

and call:

```
std::tuple<double, double> bar = foo<std::tuple<double, double>>(
        init,
        [](int init_, double mult_) { 
            double res = init_ * mult_;
            return std::make_tuple(res, 4.1);
        },
        mult
    );
```

Or move the function template into class template as static function:

```
template<typename ...Output>
struct Foo
{
template <typename Func, typename... Inputs>
static std::tuple<Output...> foo(int init, Func&& func, Inputs&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
}
};
```

and call:

```
auto bar = Foo<double, double>::foo(
        init,
        [](int init_, double mult_) { 
            double res = init_ * mult_;
            return std::make_tuple(res, 4.1);
        },
        mult
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of `foo` isn't available to deduce `Outputs...`, so they are deduced as empty.

To enforce that it returns a `std::tuple` where the first element is `double`, you can write a trait.

```
template <typename>
struct is_tuple_of_double : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Others>
struct is_tuple_of_double<std::tuple<double, Others...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_tuple_of_double_v = is_tuple_of_double<T>::value;

template<typename Func, typename... Inputs>
auto foo(int init, Func&& func, Inputs&&... args) {
    static_assert(is_tuple_of_double_v<decltype(std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...)>);
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(init, std::forward<Inputs>(args)...);
};
```